# Determinant manipulation involving variable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

This manipulation was done by somebody else and I am trying to understand what is happening:
$$\det \begin{bmatrix} \lambda-1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & \lambda - 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & \lambda -1 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ =(\lambda-1)((\lambda-1)^2-1)-1((\lambda-1)-1)+(1-\lambda+1)$$
$$ = (\lambda-2)^2(\lambda+1)$$

How did the last simplification happen?

**edit1:**

I did this manipulation:

$$\det \begin{bmatrix}\lambda-2 & 0 & -(\lambda-2)\\
0 & \lambda-2 & -(\lambda-2) \\
1 & 1 & \lambda-1 \end{bmatrix}$$

After this, can I say the following:

$$(\lambda-2)^2 \det \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & \lambda-1 \end{bmatrix}$$

if yes then why because the last row, if multiplied by $(\lambda -2)^2$, will be changed differently. And do we just leave $(\lambda -2)^2$ as it is after we find the determinant?My understanding is that since I'm taking (λ−2)2 from first two rows, I must need the same common in the third so that I can put it outside as a multiplication.Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(\lambda-1)((\lambda-1)^2-1)-1((\lambda-1)-1)+(1-\lambda+1)=$

$(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda+1)$

The last step here is wrong. It should be

$(\lambda-2)^2(\lambda+1)$

And you can get there e.g. by writing:

$(\lambda-1)((\lambda-1)^2-1)-1((\lambda-1)-1)+(1-\lambda+1)$

as

$(\lambda)(\lambda-2)(\lambda-1) - 2(\lambda-2)=$

$(\lambda)(\lambda^2-3\lambda + 2) - 2(\lambda-2)=$

$(\lambda^3-3\lambda^2 + 2\lambda) - 2(\lambda-2)=$

$(\lambda^3-3\lambda^2 + 2\lambda) - 2(\lambda-2)=$

$\lambda^3-3\lambda^2 + 4=$

$(\lambda-2)^2(\lambda+1)$

---

Regarding the second part of the question:

You are factoring out
$(\lambda - 2)$ from the first
row and $(\lambda - 2)$ from the 
second row, giving $(\lambda - 2)^2$.

This is perfectly fine. You can 
factor out any common term in any row.
You dont need to factor out anything
from the third row too.

You have theorem that says:

> A factor common to all elements of a row (or column) can be taken out as a factor of the determinant

Comment: But without following the standard manipulation,i.e.,(λ−1)((λ−1)2−1)−1((λ−1)−1)+(1−λ+1), how can you get there?Please read the bottom part of my question.

Comment: @Afif Standard manipulation is easy in this case. But your method works too, because the remaning determinant evaluates to $(\lambda + 1)$

Comment: @Afif Was there anything else or did i misunderstand you?

Comment: I'm asking why taking (λ−2)2 out does not affect the 3rd row of the determinant system.As you can see the third row has [1 1 λ−1] in the system, so how can you take (λ−2)2 common.N: B: This still gives right answer (λ−2)2(λ+1) so there must be a rationale behind this.My understanding is that since I'm taking (λ−2)2 from first two rows, I must need the same common in the third so that I can put it outside as a multiplication.Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Afif You are factoring out $(\lambda - 2)$ from the first row AND $(\lambda - 2)$ from the second row, giving $(\lambda - 2) \cdot (\lambda - 2) = (\lambda - 2)^2$ This is perfectly fine. You can factor out any common term in any row, without changing the determinant. You dont have to factor out anything from the third row too.

Comment: @Afif In fact you have a theorem that states: A factor common to all elements of a row (or column)
can be taken out as a factor of the determinant.

Comment: When i wrote "without changing the determinant" that is ofc easy to misunderstand. What i meant was that you only change it by the term you are factoring out.